# Need advice on this very odd error

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, connection-string

I am trying to establish connection to a database through:

```
Dim sqCon As SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=MegaDatabase;Integrated_Security=SSPI")
```

The problem is only on this line where it tells me that:

```
Array bounds cannot appear in type specifiers
```

The same problem does NOT appear in any of my other projects though I use this same format.

I need someone to tell me what exactly is wrong with this and how may I solve this.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Add some quotes around your connection **string**

Comment: @MrMoose please check the edited version and it still gives me the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That (original version, now changed) doesn't look anything *like* valid syntax. There's no opening `"` character and there's too many `)` characters at the end.

However, even with the fixes, I think what you probably wanted to do was to `dim` it as a **new** variable, something like:

```
Dim sqCon As New SqlConnection ("DataSource=...")
```

Comment: please check the edit I made a mistake in the code but it still does say the same thing

Comment: @Armaan, checked edit, looks to be better syntax but you're still trying to create an _array_ rather than a `new` object.

Comment: The problem was that I forget to declare it as new....sorry for wasting your time. But thanks anyhow

Answer (score 0):

use the `New` keyword

```
Dim sqCon As New SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=MegaDatabase;Integrated_Security=SSPI")
```

Comment: thanks bro I got that. Sorry for wasting your time at such a silly question